# Removing values from key - value pairs in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that holds a student's name and their score on a quiz:

```
scores = {'Sam': ['8'], 'Ben': ['8', '10', '9' ,'4'], 'Jack': ['6', '5'], 'Tim': ['9', '10', '7', '9']}
```

I would like to check the number of values in each key-value pair in the dictionary and remove 1 value if there are more than 3 values.

I have tried this:

```
if len(scores) > 3:
  dictionary.pop(1)
```

However this results in a key error.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Since this almost certainly about your [GCSE programming problem](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2gawvg/gcse_computing_programming_tasks_14_16_year_olds/), please do read [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Comment: @AvinashRaj: see the GCSE problem descriptions; I'd bet money on the OP working on Choice 2, problem c.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks I have read the letter. I have already done research into the task and shown the code that I have tried to use. The question I have asked is not taken directly from the task requirements, so I don't see the problem with asking this question.

Comment: @Tim: glad you read it; your question is one of the better ones we have received on the subject. I just wanted you to be aware of what Stack Overflow expects of such posts, and some things to think about when using Stack Overflow for your assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing *keys*, not entries from the value. You want to limit those:

```
for key in scores:
    if len(scores[key]) > 3:
        scores[key] = scores[key][:3]
```

This keeps the *first* 3 values. It'll depend on how you added those values; you may instead want to keep the *last* 3 values instead:

```
for key in scores:
    if len(scores[key]) > 3:
        scores[key] = scores[key][-3:]
```

You don't really need the `len()` test however; slicing will never throw an error if you have fewer items, so you can just use:

```
for key in scores:
    scores[key] = scores[key][-3:]
```

and it'll continue to work if there are fewer items.

You can simply re-generate the dictionary using a dictionary comprehension even:

```
scores = {student: values[-3:] for student, values in scores.items()}
```

Demo showing the last approach:

```
>>> scores = {'Sam': ['8'], 'Ben': ['8', '10', '9' ,'4'], 'Jack': ['6', '5'], 'Tim': ['9', '10', '7', '9']}
>>> {student: values[-3:] for student, values in scores.items()}
{'Tim': ['10', '7', '9'], 'Ben': ['10', '9', '4'], 'Jack': ['6', '5'], 'Sam': ['8']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `pop` you can just use slicing :

```
>>> scores = {'Sam': ['8'], 'Ben': ['8', '10', '9' ,'4'], 'Jack': ['6', '5'], 'Tim': ['9', '10', '7', '9']}
>>> scores =dict((i,j[1:]) if len(j)>3 else (i,j) for i,j in scores.items())
>>> scores
{'Tim': ['10', '7', '9'], 'Ben': ['10', '9', '4'], 'Jack': ['6', '5'], 'Sam': ['8']}
```

Comment: This removes all the other items whose value's length is <= 3.

Comment: @thefourtheye oops, yeah , i missed `else`! fixed